# Can I use JS in silverlight app?

Tags: javascript, c#, silverlight

I have Silverlight app. For example I want add some JS script which can interact with SL app. For example I want add google map use JS api. Can I do this, But I must send some data from SL to JS to add pins on map, draw figures on map ect.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc903928(v=vs.95).aspx.

Comment: Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414(v=vs.95).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359(v=vs.95).aspx can help you

Comment: You do realize there is a Bing Map control for Silverlight [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2949) with a demo available [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/).  That's going to be a whole lot easier if you're trying to embed a map in your Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Phone and you dont mind that part of the xaml to be a webview yo can.

First add a webview to the xaml

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webView" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" IsScriptEnabled="True" 
                              ScriptNotify="WebBrowser_ScriptNotify" />
```

Then you have to bind the webview with the load event and then saveg files to storage and load your html and js files

```
webView.Loaded += WebBrowser_OnLoaded;

    private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFilesToIsoStore();
        chatView.Navigate(new Uri("Assets/HtmlContent/index.html", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void SaveFilesToIsoStore()
    {
        //These files must match what is included in the application package,
        //or BinaryStream.Dispose below will throw an exception.
        string[] files = {
            "Assets/HtmlContent/index.html", 
            "Assets/HtmlContent/js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",  "Assets/HtmlContent/js/pagejs.js",  "Assets/HtmlContent/css/style.css"
        };

        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (false == isoStore.FileExists(files[0]))
        {
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(f, UriKind.Relative));
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
                {
                    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
                    SaveToIsoStore(f, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveToIsoStore(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        string strBaseDir = string.Empty;
        string delimStr = "/";
        char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
        string[] dirsPath = fileName.Split(delimiter);

        //Get the IsoStore.
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Re-create the directory structure.
        for (int i = 0; i < dirsPath.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            strBaseDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(strBaseDir, dirsPath[i]);
            isoStore.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
        }

        //Remove the existing file.
        if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        //Write the file.
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(fileName)))
        {
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
```

So on the js you have to talk to the c# like this

```
function sendMessageToCodeBehind(someData) {
    window.external.notify(JSON.stringify({ method: 'AddMessage', data: someData }));
}
```

On the code behind you would recibe the messages from the webview like this:

```
    private void WebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        var example = new { method = string.Empty, data = new object() };

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(e.Value, example);

        switch (obj.method) {
            case "methodName":
        }
    }
```

And you would send back messages to the js like this

```
webView.InvokeScript("jsMethodName", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "some json message" }));
```

Comment: he said silverlight and dindt specified. I dont have enough points to comment a question, so... my answer wasnt bad at all. I demonstrate you can do that with Silverlight, if he is not using windowsPhone he would just need to find a similar control as phone:WebBrowser and that's it

Comment: It would work in cases of Full Trust or Out-of-browser apps ... for normal browser Silverlight apps you would have to use the Javascript API (as in the links left in comments above).